# Titanium function call issue

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium

Hi I am almost new on titanium, iPhone and JS development,
I don't know how to call a function from one .js to another .js in tab group.
I have a callback in app.js and i want to call a function from another .js in tab group.
How can i do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do two things :

1> you can pass that function to a window from where you can call that function.

2> you can use custom addEventListener to call from another window like below.

app.js

```
function test(){
      alert('Hello from Function');

    Ti.App.addEventListener('callTest',test);
}
```

===================
another.js

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('callTest');
```